# Fuseki “Can't find jarfile to run”

Tags: sparql, semantic-web, jena, fuseki

I am trying set up Fuseki, and I have followed the documentation but am new to Fuseki. I specified the path in the terminal.

```
 $ /Users/rumplestilskin/Downloads/jena-fuseki-0.2.7/fuseki-server --update --mem /ds
```

I am getting the error:

```
Can't find jarfile to execute
```

I am not sure where the jarfile needs to be in order for it to be found. `fuseki-server.jar` is currently in the same directory as `fuseki-server`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set the environment variable `FUSEKI_HOME`:

```
$ /usr/local/lib/jena-fuseki-0.2.7/fuseki-server --mem /ds
Can't find jarfile to run

$ FUSEKI_HOME=/usr/local/lib/jena-fuseki-0.2.7 /usr/local/lib/jena-fuseki-0.2.7/fuseki-server --mem /ds
08:42:46 INFO  Dataset: in-memory
08:42:46 INFO  Home Directory: /usr/local/lib/jena-fuseki-0.2.7
08:42:46 INFO  Dataset path = /ds
08:42:46 INFO  Fuseki 0.2.7 2013-05-11T22:05:51+0100
08:42:46 INFO  Started 2013/06/28 08:42:46 EDT on port 3030
```

It actually seems like the `fuseki-server` script should try to guess this, based on the following code in `fuseki-server`.

```
export FUSEKI_HOME="${FUSEKI_HOME:-$PWD}"

if [ ! -e "$FUSEKI_HOME" ]
then
    echo "$FUSEKI_HOME does not exist" 1>&2
    exit 1
    fi
```

The actual description of `FUSEKI_HOME` is in the `fuseki` (not `fuseki-server`) script:

```
$ grep -B 1 -A 3 -m 1 FUSEKI_HOME /usr/local/lib/jena-fuseki-0.2.7/fuseki
#
# FUSEKI_HOME
#   Where Fuseki is installed.  If not set, the script will try
#   to guess it based on the script invokation path.
#
```

Comment: thanks Joshua, I am now trying: `rumps-imac:/ rumplestilskin$ FUSEKI_HOME=Users/rumplestilskin/downloads/jena-fuseki-0.2.7/fuseki-server Users/rumplestilskin/Downloads/jena-fuseki-0.2.7/fuseki-server REQUIRED:--mem`. I tried `--file`,`--loc` ect, but I am still getting the same error. is this correct?

Comment: @rumplestilskin Yes, the jar is now being found, and you're starting Fuseki, but you're not providing all the arguments its needs.  You still need to provide the command line arguments, e.g., `--mem /ds`, as you did in your original example, and as I did in my example.

Comment: @rumplestilskin Glad to hear it!  I actually had this exact problem yesterday.  Enough applications require `FOO_HOME` to be set that I just looked at the script and checked, but if you're not used to doing that, it can be a real mystery.